# How to use secondary workflow on Task list to set Due Date?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

can someone point me to a simple answer here - i have a list that has a primary workflow that fires a custom task. i want to create a workflow on the task list to update the Due Date to be a field from the primary list.  Possible?

Comment: i tried to do this:

Comment: If "Current Item: Workflow Name" equals "Setup Signoff Artifacts for Project", Set "Due Date" to <lookup for date and time, set to the primary list and field, but i can't figure out what the "find the list item" data should be to bring back the correct record in the lookup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry no that wasn't the answer.  here's the answer:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-secondary-workflow-HA010237656.aspx

and in relation to your specific question above:

Why you need a secondary workflow for managing task due dates

The primary workflow that creates a task item pauses as soon as the task item has been created and assigned.

While the primary workflow is paused, it cannot set the Due Date value of the task item, check the completion status of the task when the due date arrives, or take appropriate action for task items that are not complete by their due dates.

A secondary workflow running on the Tasks list, however, can perform all of these functions while the primary workflow is still paused.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating a task in a list, using a workflow on a Project list - and you want the task due date to be related to the project due date.

Can the workflow creating the task set the date at creation?